# android ANR in MediaPlayer reset

Tags: android, media-player

I've got a simple activity which plays video through VideoView

```
public class AVideo extends Activity {
private VideoView mVideoView;
private MediaController mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_video);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Uri path = Uri.parse(extras.getString("videoURI"));
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(path);
    mc = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mVideoView.start();
    mc.show();
}
}
```

In some cases when user pushes back button, on this activity, before video starts playing, he's got ANR.
Here's my traces:

```
DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=3 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001b268 self=0xbd00
| sysTid=423 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1344001384
at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1028)
at android.widget.VideoView.release(VideoView.java:476)
at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:49)
at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceDestroyed(VideoView.java:467)
at android.view.SurfaceView.reportSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceView.java:488)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:413)
at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:189)
at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:3782)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:692)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:692)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:692)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:706)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also logcat shows this:

```
07-01 15:11:40.408: WARN/libutils.threads(2967): Thread (this=0x22818): don't call
waitForExit() from this Thread object's thread. It's a guaranteed deadlock!
```

I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742589/android-mediaplayer-bug-when-using-reset-and-release-calls) and [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=959), but there are no solution.

Comment: I got the same problem, have you solve it?

Comment: @dreamtale well, i just use an intent to launch user's video player

Comment: Have you implemented onPause and onDestroy to correctly clean up the resources?

Comment: Try that. Make sure you leave the media objects in a defined state.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the ANR message, means that your applicaction is insufficiently responsive for a period of time, use **[runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)** to run the specified action on the UI thread or [**Asynctask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
    public class AVideo extends Activity {
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private MediaController mc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_video);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Uri path = Uri.parse(extras.getString("videoURI"));
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                 
                            mVideoView.setVideoURI(path);
                    }
                });

        mc = new MediaController(this);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mVideoView.start();
        mc.show();
    }
  }
```

Try implementing setOnPreparedListener to start the video.

```
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {                 
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.i("VIDEO", "onCompletion");                 
        }
    });
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {             
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.i("VIDEO", "onPrepared");
              if(mVideoView.canSeekForward()) mVideoView.seekTo(mVideoView.getDuration()/5); 
              mVideoView.start();                   
        }
    });
    mVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
```

Comment: onCreate by default gets called on UI thread, whats point of using runOnUiThread to set the setVideoURI

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AVideo extends Activity {
private VideoView mVideoView;
private MediaController mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_video);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Uri path = Uri.parse(extras.getString("videoURI"));
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(path);
    mc = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mVideoView.start();
    mc.show();
}

}
```